# Can't dispose of jframe window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, dispose

I'm trying to dispose of the difficulty window after any one of the difficulty button's are clicked but it won't happen. I've tried `.dispose` and `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` but i can't get it. Is it just placement or more?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class Game extends JFrame{

    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();


    private JLabel lab;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game difficulty = new Game();
    difficulty.setSize(350,105);
    difficulty.setTitle("Difficulty.");
    difficulty.setVisible(true);
    difficulty.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    /**Game sudoku = new Game();
    sudoku.setSize(900, 900);
    sudoku.setVisible(false);*/

}   


public Game(){

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    lab = new JLabel("Please select your difficulty.");
    add(lab);

    JButton easy;
    easy = new JButton("Easy");
    add(easy);

     easy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("You clicked the button");
                JFrame.dispose();
            }
        });   


    JButton medium;
    medium = new JButton("Medium");
    add(medium);

    JButton hard;
    hard = new JButton("Hard");
    add(hard);

    JButton evil;
    evil = new JButton("Evil!");
    add(evil);

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dispose()` method is not a static, so it'll not work by calling it directly from `JFrame` class

```
JFrame.dispose();
```

try to do :

```
dispose();
```

Or to dispose the `frame` object you have created

```
frame.dispose();
```

Read more about [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Answer (score 7):

First of all you're extending JFrame and creating an object of JFrame, if I'm not wrong, this shouldn't be done.

```
public class Game extends JFrame{

    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

And as [@Salah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945767/2180785) said, JFrame is not static, so it should be:

```
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

To solve your problem, you're disposing a new JFrame (yes, you have 3 JFrames in one class, instead of 1, which is what you want), with: `JFrame.dispose();` if you already created an object or you're extending JFrame, you can:

```
this.dispose(); //For the extended JFrame
```

or

```
frame.dispose(); //For the object you created
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem:

```
this.dispose();
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the jFrame to invisible before disposing it:

```
public void disposeJFrame(JFrame frame){
    frame.setVisible(false);
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're wanting to close the whole program, you can use System.exit(0);

Answer (score -1):

Instead `JFrame.dispose();`, use `frame.dispose()` or `JFrame.this.dispose();`